# How to use a custom format for multi-column display fields?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Is anyone aware of a way of expanding the 'normal' uses of this (it's `id` by default and easily changed to `field1`)? I have one displayField sets follows:

```
$this->displayField(['name', 'desc']);
```

Which displays as `Name; Description` when called in a template file. I know it's a fudge, but it there a way I can manipulate this to have it display `Name - Description` for example, just by using the `displayField`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a virtual field, and specify that to be used as display field instead of using multiple columns, something along the lines of

```
// ...

class YourEntity extends Entity
{
    // ...

    protected function _getNameDesc()
    {
        return
            $this->_properties['name'] .
            ' - ' .
            $this->_properties['desc'];
    }
}
```

```
// ...

class YourTable extends Table
{
    // ...

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->displayField('name_desc');

        // ...
    }
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entites > Creating Virtual Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields)**

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for that and the edits too. Appreciated.