# Is it possible to use a virtual field as the display field for an entity?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a virtual field that outputs a formatted string:

```
protected function _getDisplayName(){
  return $this->ref.' - '.$this->name;
}
```

I'm trying to use this output as the display filed like so:

```
$this->displayField('display_name');
```

But it seems to ignore it and display the enire object. Is this actually possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425881/how-to-use-a-custom-format-for-multi-column-display-fields) and the relative answer. Your code is correct, but I suppose you are misunderstanding what displayField does: displayField is usefull just when your are usind `find('list')`

Comment: Yes your right, I'm getting mixed up. I hate Mondays!