# Changing default title of table and attribute name

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I've been doing a lot of research on the subject however I can't find anything about it.

I'd like to change the default `title` of an Employee table I created, however the scaffolding displays the `id` of the employee as a title.

example of a table title (see the red text label at the top):

[image: example of a table title (see the red text label at the top)]

Is there a way to change the default title of the table to a custom string such as `Employees.first_name + Employees.last_name` instead of just `Employee.id` somewhere in the Model configuration?

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999490/how-do-i-create-a-keyvalue-pair-display-field-by-combining-having-two-fields-i**

Comment: @ndm Thank you for the quick response, I discovered virtual and display fields just 5 minutes ago. However changing `$this->setVirtualField(string key)` in `EmployeesTable` does not seem to affect the scaffolding at all, as the `id` is still displaying. Is there something else I need to know?

Comment: Sorry, I've posted the wrong link: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425881/how-to-use-a-custom-format-for-multi-column-display-fields**

Comment: @ndm The virtual field is working right now, however the display field does not seem to be changing anything in the scaffolding. I meant to say `$this->setDisplayField(string key)` in my previous comment.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to be working properly in dropdown lists that reference to it.

Comment: I misread your question a little bit... you cannot practically change the ID there, as the primary key usage is hard coded in the generated template (`view.ctp`). You'll have to modify the template.

Comment: @ndm Makes sense, Thank you for the help!